# How could I use a text box for user input as a MySql query, then display the results in another text box?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Using VB.net, the result I am looking for is essentially an extremely watered down version of "Query Browser" for example. I want the user to be able to input a MySql query in a text box, then display those results in a different text box to the user. I am new, so this might be totally ridiculous to ask, just curious if anyone has any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: what if they enter `Truncate Table table_name`?

Comment: It's more of a tool of convenience for people who better know better than to do something so idiotic. These same people have the access you speak of already anyway, just trying to make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows Forms rather than WFP, Web Forms, or other.

Instead of a TextBox for the results, use a [DataGridView control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz(v=vs.110).aspx). Let's call it `DataGridView1`. If your TextBox is called `TextBox1` and you have a button named `btnExecuteQuery`, you'd need code that looks something like this:

```vb
Private Sub RunQuery(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExecuteQuery.Click
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection("connection string here"), _
          cmd As New MySqlCommand(TextBox1.Text, cn)

          cn.Open()
          DataGridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    End Using
End Sub
```

You'll also need [the MySql Connector for .Net](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html).